# Jquery.Validate Based on Condition

Tags: jquery, validation, select, conditional-statements

I am trying to do conditional validation using Jquery.Validate()

I have a select named selectAmount
and an inpute named txtAmount

If selectAmount value = "Other"

I'd like for txtAmount to be required.

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="AddForm" method="POST" action="#">

                    <select name="selectAmount">
                        <option value="10">$10</option>
                        <option value="25">$25</option>
                        <option value="50">$50</option>
                        <option value="100">$100</option>
                        <option value="250">$250</option>
                        <option value="500">$500</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>

                    <input name="txtAmount" type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" />
            <button id="AddToCart">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's where I'm setting the rules.
The problem I'm having is here:

```
"txtAmount": {
                required: function(element){
                    alert($("#selectAmount").val());
                    return false;

$('#selectAmount').val() //is always undefined

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#AddForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "selectAmount" : {
            required: true
        },
        "txtAmount": {
            required: function(element){
                alert($("#selectAmount").val());
                return $("#selectAmount").val() == 'Other';
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {

        "selectAmount": {
            required: "Amount selection is required."
        },

        "txtAmount": {
            required: "Amount is required."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/9YjH2/2/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close. The `#` in `$("#selectAmount")` is telling jQuery to find the element with the `id` of selectAmount. But selectAmount is a `name` attribute not an `id`. So if you simply add the `id=selectAmount` attribute to your `select` everything works out fine. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YjH2/4/) (with the alert commented out). Also here is some more info on [jQuery selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) If you do not want to add an `id` attribute, take a look at the [attribute equals selector.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) However, I would recommend using the `id`.

So in the end just change this line:
`<select name="selectAmount">`
to
`<select name="selectAmount" id="selectAmount">`